# Importar csv ORACLE

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, csv, select, importación

como podría importar un archivo CSV mediante un procedimiento. La base de datos es ORACLE 12c y tengo un usuario que solo me permite hacer LECTURA a la BASE es decir que muchos privilegios no tengo como por ejemplo hacer un GRANT.
Encontré este código pero estuvo investigando que para hacer " DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_dir1 " primero debo crear un directorio y luego otorgar permisos cosa que no puedo hacer.
¿Como podría encarar este tema?

````
INSERT INTO target_table(time_id, prod_id, quantity_sold, amount_sold)
SELECT time_id, prod_id, quantity_sold, amount_sold
FROM   EXTERNAL (   
    (time_id        DATE NOT NULL,     
     prod_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
     quantity_sold  NUMBER(10,2),
     amount_sold    NUMBER(10,2))     
    TYPE Oracle_LOADER     
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_dir1
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
      RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|')     
   LOCATION ('sales_9.csv') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED) sales_external; ```
````

Comment: si solo tienes lectura no podras hacer inserts... asi que tu pregunta no tiene solucion al menos que te den los permisos requeridos..

Comment: Pregúntale primero al DBA.

Comment: Gracias Gente...le pregunte al DBA pero no es posible, de todas maneras lo estoy resolviendo por ahora con KNIME